# I load resource in another thread when game start,I use an Task class,and Put the task of loading the resource into it. It doesn't always work

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock

It works in Release mode, but it will no respond in Debug mode.

Here is the code of my `Task` class:

```
class Task
{
public:
    Task()
    {

        thread_ = std::thread([this]() 
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                std::function<void(void)> task;
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex_);
                    condition_.wait(lock, [this]() 
                    {
                        auto id = std::this_thread::get_id();
                        CCLOG("save thread %d : notify saveThread",id);
                        return this->stop || !this->tasks.empty();
                    });

                    if (this->stop&&this->tasks.empty())
                        return;
                    task = tasks.front();
                    tasks.pop();
                }
                auto id = std::this_thread::get_id();
                CCLOG("save thread %d : start save data ",id);
                task();
            }
        });
    }

    ~Task()
    {
        if (!stop)
        {
            stopTask();
        }
    }

    void equeue(std::function<void(void)>  func)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
            if (stop)
                return;
            tasks.push(func);
        }
        condition_.notify_one();
    }

    void stopTask()
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex_);
            stop = true;
            while (!tasks.empty())
                tasks.pop();

        }
        condition_.notify_all();
        thread_.join();;
    }
private:
    std::thread thread_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable condition_;
    std::queue<std::function<void(void)>> tasks;
    bool stop = false;
};
```

and here is my work code:

```
    class PreloadScene : public cc::CreateT<PreloadScene,cc::BaseScene>
{
public:
    void init();
     ...
private:
    bool preLoadDone_ = false;
    int32_t preLoadTimer_ = 0;
    Task task;
};
void PreloadScene::init()
{
  task.equeue([this]()
    {
        while (!preLoadDone_)
        {
            doLoadLogic();
        }
    });
}
```

I don't know why is that behaviour in Debug mode?
I click on the interrupt. The parallel stack is as follows:

[image]

The same code works in `Xcode`.
I try to use `std::thread` directly, which is fine.
So I suspect it has to do with `st::unique_lock` or viusal studio in Debug mode.

I hope someone can help me with that?

Comment: I think you have 2 race conditions. On the `bool preLoadDone_` and on the `bool stop`. You may use an atomic for the first one. For the second you could aquire the lock in the destructor of your taskclass. I dont think this will fix your problem, still you should make your code threadsafe.

Comment: Your taskqueue in the task class is under a race condition too. When enqueuing you need the lock too.

Comment: I know.but 'bool preLoadDone_' set true only when the resource load is complete, and In the main thread only read,It should not be used atomic.I shouldn't have used 'stopTask' ,just  need to get the lock in the destructor and handle it.

Comment: "It should not be used atomic" What do you mean? You have to use atomic, else this is undefined behaviour.